# Class initialized even autostartup is false in Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I have query  regarding Spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer.
I am trying to autostartup based on property.

```
<bean id="MyAckContainer" lazy-init="true"   class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="MyAcknowledgementFactory"/>
    <property name="exceptionListener" ref="MyAcknowledgementFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>        
    <property name="autoStartup" value="${enableMyFlow:false}"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="MyAcknowledgementSource"/>
    <property name="recoveryInterval" value="10000"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="MyResponseQueue"/>
```

However even if 'enableMyFlow' is 'false', MyAcknowledgementSource gets initialized. 
Am i missing something here or spring invokes all the refs before checking the autostartup?

Comment: A bean is created regardless of that setting, what it doesn't do is start to listen for messages.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense now.